# Using several instances of a parent class in a child class in Python

Tags: class, inheritance, multiple-instances

I am building an application in Finance. I have a Schedule object that I would like to use several times in a child class. The child object has multiple schedules.

I can simplify the problem as follows: a person has two addresses, a school address and a home address. I am modelling this as an Address Class having two children: a Person Class and a School Class. Finally a Student Class is a child of both a Person and a School.
This creates a confusion in the Address. How to solve this:

My sample code that does not work is as follows :

class Address:
def **init**(self, street, town):
self.streetname = street
self.townname = town

class Person(Address):
def **init**(self, fname, lname, street, town):
Address.**init**(self, street, town)
self.firstname = fname
self.lastname = lname

class School(Address):
def **init**(self, name, street, town):
Address.**init**(self, street, town)
self.sname = name

class Student(Person, School):
def **init**(self, fname, lname, sname, pstreet, ptown, sstreet, stown):
Person.**init**(self, fname, lname, pstreet, ptown)
School.**init**(self, sname, sstreet, stown)

x = Student("John", "Doe", "High School", "Home Street", "Home Town", "School Street", "School Town")

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the concept of inheritance.
`Person` and `School` should not be child classes of `Address`.
Student should be a child class of Person, but not of school.

Both `Persons` and `Schools` *have* an `Address`, but they aren't some sub-type of `Address`.
A `Student` *is* a `Person`, it is a more specific type of person (sub-type) so it should be a child class of `Person`.
A `Student` *is not* a `School`, a student attends a school. So the `Student` should have a `School` that is associated with them as an attribute.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think this solves my problem. I will reorganise my data accordingly.